# protobuf arena allocation compilation error

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

.proto file

```
message arena_alloc
{
optional int32 submerged=1;
};
```

in generated files there is constructor

```
arena_alloc(const arena_alloc& from);
```

using arena allocation am trying to create the object using this constructor

```
test::arena_alloc *c,d;
c=google::protobuf::Arena::CreateMessage<test::arena_alloc>(&arena,d);
```

During compilation this error is thrown

```
  google/protobuf/arena.h:478:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘test::arena_alloc::arena_alloc(std::nullptr_t,
    test::arena_alloc&)’
             return new T(nullptr, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

But if i create using new operator it works fine.How to do the same using arenas?

Comment: You can drop the `,d` bit off can't you?

Comment: i want to create the object with d contents.am trying to do this by copy constructor

Comment: I haven't used the arena allocator before but looking at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/arenas) that constructor is used allocate the object within that arena.  It's not clear what you are trying to acheive.  You are trying to construct a new `arena_alloc` by copying what exactly?

Comment: am trying to call the copy constructor.if i do 'c=new test::arena_alloc(d)' it works as expected.i.e copy constructor is called.Instead of new i want to use arena

Comment: Ah I understand; yeah I don't see why that doesn't work.  However the compiler is looking for `std::nullptr_t, test::arena_alloc&` so show the declaration of `arena`.

Comment: @trojanfoe show the declaration of arena? i dint get you

Comment: You are referencing a variable called `arena`. Show its declaration.

Comment: google::protobuf::Arena arena; nothing special.